# why short is incompatible to int in the context of overriding?

Tags: java, overriding, int, primitive, short

I have a subclass named child which inherits a class named parent. I am trying to override the method in the super class. I have experimented a little. I have created the overriden method with its return type short which is the subtype of int. As far I know I can do so. And the method is legally overriden. whenever I call the method with the reference of the super class, the compiler generates an incompatible return type error. What's the problem here ? My code is given below:

```
class parent
{

    int test()
    {
        System.out.println("called inside parent\n");
        return 1;
    }
}

class child extends parent
{

    short test()
    {
        System.out.println("called inside child\n");
        return 1;
    }
}

class Myclass
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        parent a=new child();
        a.test();
    }
}
```

Comment: you can use `java.lang.Number` class type instead of primitive type, then you can override it with `Integer` or `Short` or `Double`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> short which is the subtype of int

Wrong, it is not. The value range of `short` is a *subset* of that of `int`, but this is a totally different issue. A `short` value can indeed be *converted to* an `int` (even implicitly), still a `short` *is not* an `int`.

Primitive types are not regular classes, so these can't have supertype/subtype relationships. Therefore you can't use contravariance of return type in this case: once you declared a return type of `int` in the base method, all of its overrides must return `int`.

Answer (score 1):

> I have created the overriden method with its return type short which is the subtype of int.

No, `short` is not a subtype of `int` (it is not so that `int` can be regarded as a superclass of `short`).

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the same signature for method overriding.

```
short test()
```

is different from

```
int test()
```

It is not limited to Java. This goes for C# too, I think.

Comment: yap that's the trivial way of overriding. But Why this is incompatibility error ?

Comment: I think it goes deep in the compiler and how it interprets data types.

Answer (score 0):

You can not differentiate the methods based on there return type except when classes in return type have parent-child relation. Even in that case you can only downcast in method which is overriding. In case of int & short, they being primitive data-type, no such relationship exists.